Alternative for autoHighlight while using MVTLayer on Deck.GL
What I am intending to do is a highlight a point on MVT layer when it is picked. I am using Deck.GL with react. I already tried using autoHighlight but it doesn't seem to work with MVTLayer. Is there any workaround for this?
